# Reflexive constructions instead of the Passive in usage?

Tags: sentence-structure, reflexive, passive

I find the passive construction quite fun to use. However I had not come across the use of a reflexive construction instead of the passive before. The reflexive constructions sound very unusual to my native english ear. For example:

> Der Schlüssel wird sich sicher noch finden

vs

> Der Schlüssel wird sicher noch gefunden werden

oder

> Das Buch liest sich schnell

vs

> Das Buch kann schnell gelesen werden

Are the reflexive constructions used commonly in everyday speech? Or is my library book (2003) too outdated? I'd definitely struggle to understand the reflexive construction, and would probably think someone had said to me that their book can read fast.

The other difficulty for me would be recognising it's tense. They sound like the the present (e.g. wird finden = will find) but can future tenses like that simply be created just by turning it reflexive?

For example could I just say for *"My email will be sent tomorrow"*

> Meine Email wird sich morgen schicken?

Comment: (Note that it’s "E-Mail" instead of "Email".)

Comment: It's really interesting that English, as a language much closer to German, does not have this feature, while my native Serbocroatian (a Slavic language) has literally the same construct ("the book reads itself quickly") so the German phrase sounds completely logical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the reflexive constructions used commonly in everyday speech?

**Yes, they are.**

> Der Schlüssel wird sich sicher[lich] noch finden

is perfectly correct and quite commonly used. To the speaker it's probable that either he himself or somebody else finds the key.

> Der Schlüssel wird sicher noch gefunden werden

is basically the same, **but** in contrast it is a bit **more cumbersome**, sounds **more official** and puts more distance to the idea, that you will find the key yourself. It can be used in more serious situations. If a boy got lost for hours already, you'd rather use

> Der Junge wird sicher noch gefunden werden.

---

> [...] but can future tenses like that simply be created just by turning it reflexive?

**They cannot** be turned into future tense by using *reflexive* but by using *reflexive* plus (a form of) *werden*.

The former example is in future tense, though you might use present tense. In this case *noch* will be used most probably (not necessarily) to show it is not yet found, whereas it's no problem to omit it, when using future tense

> Der Schlüssel findet sich sicher[lich] **noch**.
> Der Schlüssel wird sich sicher[lich] finden.

You'd also prefer the **noch** version when you want to say something like ***for now** I stop looking for it (I'll do that later)*

In contrast

> Meine Email wird sich morgen schicken?

is not correct. There are only certain verbs used in that manner.

> Roggenbrötchen verkaufen sich gut.
> Das neue Gebäck wird sich gut verkaufen.

Here you have present and future tense (like in your examples).

Answer (score 4):

1. The reflexive constructions you *cite* (`sich finden`, `sich lesen`) are used commonly in everyday speech in *these* contexts.
2. `Das Buch liest sich sehr schnell.` is even more common than the passive alternative `Das Buch kann schnell gelesen werden.`.
3. The reflexive construction you *make up* (`sich schicken`) just doesn't exist. The passive construction is to be used here: `Meine Email wird morgen (ab-)geschickt werden.`
4. `Der Schlüssel *wird* sich sicher noch finden.` is in future tense.
5. `Das Buch *liest* sich schnell.` is in present tense.

Comment: And even though `Meine Email wird morgen (ab-)geschickt werden.`is grammatically correct it is not a phrase that would be commonly used in German.

Comment: @SAnderka But that's no issue of German but of the email usage. Most eleborated email servers, email applications or even cron-jobs allow scheduled sending of emails. If you use scheduled sending of emails. This sentence would be a common way to do so. Scheduled sending of emails itself is just not common.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't think about scheduled email services.